How do I check if something is a dataframe?
This seems like it should be simple.... but...
I am trying to write a function where I first want to make sure that what has been passed into it is actually a dataframe. So something like:
def function(df1,arg2,arg2):
    if isinstance(df1,pd.DataFrame)==False:
        raise TypeError("Sorry, but data needs to be a DataFrame")


Where I have set pd as short for pandas.
Is this even a valid way of doing things? Or if not what should I be doing to make sure df1 being passed is a dataframe?
I have seen a few similar questions here, but nothing quite the same.

Yes, this sounds correct. Though in Python the approach is to usually either:

Not check the type, and handle the runtime errors if the object type is incompatible. This is called duck typing, and has the advantage of working with similar-but-not-identical types, like DataFrames from other libraries.
Add type annotations and check them with an external tool like mypy. Note that by default Python will ignore type annotations!

Your approach is a fine middle-way, and it's correctly using isinstance so it should be compatible with subclasses too.
